# How can i show my result from database on JSP by spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i have a connection, controller class and jsp file , i want to pass the data which i get from sql query of  PostgreSQL into jsp.

i am new in spring: is there any one can help me. thanks

this is my connection class:

```
public class PostGisConnection {
    public Connection getConn(){


        Connection connection = null;
        try{


            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/imposm3";
            String user = "postgres";
            String passwd = "mypass";

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);


        String query1="Select * from imposm3";
        Statement mystmt = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet myRrs = mystmt.executeQuery(query1);
         while (myRrs.next()) {
         System.out.println(myRrs.getString("id") + ", " + myRrs.getString("tags") + "," + myRrs.getString("geom"));


            }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/createObject")
    public String viewSchema() {
        return "/index";
    }

}
```

and this is my jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
<head>

    <title>saeed</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <form action="/createObject" method="GET" >

    <table>
  <tr>
    <th>OSM_ID</th>
    <th>TAGS</th>
    <th>GEOMETRY</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Store the DB results in some bean, return the list of bean in a ModelAndView, and use a jstl forEach in the jsp? See this for example: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-and-list-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use seperate method in post `PostGisConnection` to get the data from database.

```
public Map<String, String> getdatafromdatabase()
{
 String query1="Select * from imposm3";
        Statement mystmt = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet myRrs = mystmt.executeQuery(query1);
  Map<String, String> details= new HashMap<String, String>();
         while (myRrs.next()) {
  details.put("id", myRrs.getString("id"));
  details.put("tags", myRrs.getString("tags"));
  details.put("geom",myRrs.getString("geom"));
          }
return details;
}
```

Then call this method in controller class in post method.use Modal attributes to send data from controller to jsp. You have to maintain a bean class for your attributes(id,tag,geom). I cant able to find any bean class so I cant able to code in your question further. Try hello world and crud operation in spring mvc.
In jsp use C:foreach method to display your records.Make sure the model attribute in controller class and jsp same.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-hashmap-form-example/
crud operation in spring mvc
http://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-crud-example